# AES and CBC in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, aes

I am trying to encrypt a string in php using AES-128 and CBC, but when I call `mcrypt_generic_init()` it returns false.

```
$cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '',MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
$iv_size = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($cipher);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

$res = mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, 'aaaa', $iv); //'aaaa' is a test key
```

Can someone tell me why is returning 0/false? I read the php documentation and seems correct 
(http://us.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php)

Comment: Are there any warnings in the log? Do `mcrypt_module_open`, `mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size` and `mcrypt_create_iv` return proper values or is there `false` return among them?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! $cipher = Resource id #3; $iv_size = 16; and $iv = š7~®1þ´X¥©>Ýõ¶;  Is $iv a weird value? (no Warning in the log)

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to encrypt a string in php using AES-128 and CBC,

[Are you sure about that?](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly) AES-CBC doesn't offer message integrity. This makes your application vulnerable to a [padding oracle attack](https://robertheaton.com/2013/07/29/padding-oracle-attack/).

Also, [mcrypt is a bad library](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong).